# Prove there is an $A \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $K(i)=\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt[4]{A})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-13+2\sqrt{13}})$. $K$ is normal over $\mathbb{Q}$

> Prove there is an $A \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $K(i)=\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt[4]{A})$

So we need to show that $K(i)=\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{-13+2\sqrt{13}})=\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt[4]{A})$

So does this mean we must show that $[\mathbb{Q}: K]=[\mathbb{Q} : \sqrt[4]{A})]$?

To me it seems intuitive that such an $A$ exists since there are two square roots in the extension (one embedded in the other). How could we find an $A$ that satisfies this?

---

I was wondering if we could use the fact that if $C \subset B \subset A$ then $[A:C]=[A:B] \times [B:C]$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $ K $ contains a root of $ x^4 + 26x^2 + 117 $ over $ \mathbb{Q} $, which factors as
 $$ (x^2 + 13 - 2\sqrt{13})(x^2 + 13 + 2\sqrt{13}) $$
It is irreducible by Eisenstein, therefore the extension is of degree $ 4 $. To see normality of $ K/\mathbb{Q} $ it is sufficient to note that

$$ \sqrt{-13 + 2\sqrt{13}} \cdot \sqrt{-13 - 2\sqrt{13}} = 3\sqrt{13} $$

so that $ \sqrt{-13 - 2\sqrt{13}} \in K $, and $ K $ is therefore the splitting field of $ x^4 + 26x^2 + 117 $ over $ \mathbb{Q} $.

It is easy to check directly that the Galois group of $ K/\mathbb{Q} $ is cyclic of order $ 4 $, therefore $ i \notin K $ and $ K(i) $ has degree $ 8 $ over $ \mathbb{Q} $. But then $ K(i) $ is an abelian extension of $ \mathbb{Q} $, and any extension of the form $ \mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt[4]{A}) $ which is of degree $ 8 $ over $ \mathbb{Q} $ is not. Therefore, we cannot have $ K(i) = \mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt[4]{A}) $.

Comment: But the question asks us to find an $A$ which satisfies $K(i)=\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt[4]{A})$ so it is true

Comment: It isn't - the question is probably wrong.

Comment: yes your are right. I meant to right there is an $A \in \mathbb{Q}(i)$.. does this work now? (I shall edit my question)

Comment: It doesn't. The exact same argument applies if $ \mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt[4]{A})/\mathbb{Q} $ is normal, and if it isn't then it obviously cannot equal $ K(i) $ which is normal over $ \mathbb{Q} $.